# Changing Background Image Label...nothing happening

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce

So I'm working in the BigCommerce platform, trying to change the background image of certain labels on a page. I can't do it with CSS alone, since I can't edit the HTML for these specific elements. Here is a link to the page that I'm trying to accomplish this on:

http://weddingsflowerpetal.mybigcommerce.com/a-vintage-affair-bouquet/

I'm trying to change the background for the labels that say "White", "Black", "Red", etc. Right now I have this code:

```
 document.getElementById("7eff70453e41b167e40002762d6195d7").style.backgroundImage="url('http://weddingsflowerpetal.mybigcommerce.com/templates/__custom/images/ribbons/blackribbon.png') no-repeat left";
```

And I have one for each of the label elements, to change each one to the right image. Now, when I put the code into the page, it gives me no JS errors, but the images don't change.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. If not a solution to my problem, is there an easier way to do this that I have yet to consider?

Comment: An element should not start with a number. You should also provide the `background-repeat` and `background-position` properties separately.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in addition to the points mentioned above, I don't think that quotes are necessary in a background image name / address. I'm basing this on css, where it is, indeed, not needed. Also, I seem to recall the order being [ positioning ] [ repeat ] instead of the other way around. But, as mentioned before, they cannot be included this way.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with what W3C says " ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z])" .. seeing Firefox is the most compliant browser it might not work in that.. But could work in others.. That's where I would start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are setting the `backgroundImage` property in JS but you're adding the other CSS text after the url. Should be 
`document.getElementById("7eff70453e41b167e40002762d6195d7").style.background='...'` or

`document.getElementById("7eff70453e41b167e40002762d6195d7").style.backgroundImage='url...';`
then 
`document.getElementById("7eff70453e41b167e40002762d6195d7").style.backgroundPosition='left';`
then
`document.getElementById("7eff70453e41b167e40002762d6195d7").style.backgroundRepeat='no-repeat';`

However, I notice that the website is using jQuery. So you might be able to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[id='7eff70453e41b167e40002762d6195d7']")
        .css("background-image", "url('http://weddingsflowerpetal.mybigcommerce.com/templates/__custom/images/ribbons/blackribbon.png')")
        .css("background-repeat", "no-repeat")
        .css("background-position", "left top");
});
```

Or you could try putting it on the `li` parent

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[id='7eff70453e41b167e40002762d6195d7']").closest("li")
        .css("background-image", "url('http://weddingsflowerpetal.mybigcommerce.com/templates/__custom/images/ribbons/blackribbon.png')")
        .css("background-repeat", "no-repeat")
        .css("background-position", "left top");
});
```